# Kindle Store opens web browser instead of its native Kindle store

Tags: amazon-kindle

On my new Samsung S5, when I press Kindle Store button, it opens web browser view and not the native Kindle store.

Any help?

Comment: What Kindle store button? Since we can't see your phone, you have to describe very clearly exactly what steps you take.

Comment: Inside Kindle app you can click on cart icon to buy ebook etc... Doing this kindle app show the content like using a browser and not native app. I hope you understand better (sorry for my poor English ).

Answer (score 0):

Here install it again - [Amazon Kindle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle&hl=en).
Comment if not worked.

Comment: I've tried that. But same problem. I'd same problem with other Android tablet and I'd resolved, but I don't remember how....

Comment: I think that this app is kind of designed like that because I have tried it for myself yesterday.

Comment: I don't think so because on my mediacom tablet the Kindle store open like in native app. The Kindle version is the same. I repeat the problem was also in this tablet but for some reason was resolved but but I don't remember how I did....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to re-enable the Samsung Apps (or whatever it's called) and download the Kindle for Samsung app, which works fine.